# System.IndexOutOfRangeException when converting from string

Tags: c#, .net, exception, mono, indexoutofboundsexception

I've got the following namespace method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration;

namespace ServiceLayer.Web.Core.Utilities
{
    private T GetInternal<T>(string configName)
    {
        var value = ((string) GetConfigSetting(configName));
        var conv = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
        return (T) conv.ConvertFromString(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? "" : value);
    }
    public string GetConfigSetting(string configName)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[configName];
    }
}
```

which aims at reading a value from the config based on its *configName*, e.g.

```
foo_value = applicationBase.GetConfigSetting("Foo", false);
```

However the code fails in *GetInternal()* with *System.IndexOutOfRangeException* when *value* is *null*.

> {System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. at System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom (System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object value) [0x0001…}
>
> at System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom (System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object value) [0x00017] in /private/tmp/source-mono-d15-3/bockbuild-d15-3/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/System/compmod/system/componentmodel/basenumberconverter.cs:89

---

Previously I've changed this line of code:

```
return (T) conv.ConvertFromString(value);
```

into:

```
return (T) conv.ConvertFromString(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? "" : value);
```

to fix the previous exception when *value* was *null*:

> System.NotSupportedException: Int32Converter cannot convert from (null).
>
> at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.GetConvertFromException (System.Object value) [0x0001c] in /private/tmp/source-mono-d15-3/bockbuild-d15-3/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/System/compmod/system/componentmodel/TypeConverter.cs:260 
>     at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFrom (System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object value) [0x00011] in /private/tmp/source-mono-d15-3/bockbuild-d15-3/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/System/compmod/system/componentmodel/TypeConverter.cs:115 
>     at System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom (System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object value) [0x000c2] in /private/tmp/source-mono-d15-3/bockbuild-d15-3/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/System/compmod/system/componentmodel/basenumberconverter.cs:110 
>     at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFromString (System.String text) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-d15-3/bockbuild-d15-3/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/System/compmod/system/componentmodel/TypeConverter.cs:137

but instead I got another.

---

What I'm doing wrong and how to fix it? Especially how to handle the conversion from string when *value* is *null*?

---

[image: C#: {System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array]

[image: C#: {System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array]

Comment: Why don't we simply check for `value` been `null` before converting it to T and return hard-coded result of `default(T)` ? Is it supposed to be null ?

Comment: Can you please show us calling part?

Comment: You can try something like this before converting value : `if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) { return default(T); } `

Comment: The code doesn't show _Stacktrace_, just _[External Code]_, so I can't check the calling part. I've attached the image.

Comment: How it can throw `IndexOutOfRangeException` if the `ConvertFromString()` throwing only `NotSupportedException`s?  [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25ds5cb6(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is doing that code, is just finding some value from config file, which is string, then creating from that string some object and casting it to generic type `T` and returning it.

You can use this method, if you want return "number" when its "number" type (int, short, long, etc), or `null` when it's string:

```
private T GetInternal<T>(string configName)
{ 
    string value = GetConfigSetting(configName);

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            return default(T);

    TypeConverter conv = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
    return (T)conv.ConvertFromString(value);
}
```

Also, why use `var` if type is known in that point, casting `GetConfigSetting()` method into `string` is completely unnecessary (or maybe that method by itsef), because it's already returning `string`. You can use just:

```
. . .
string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[configName];
. . .
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
return (T) conv.ConvertFromString(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? "0" : value);
```

Comment: May be this fixed the exceptions, but if you pass, for example, a `string` as `T`, you will get `0` as result (not "" or `null`).

Comment: Slight change to the ternary statement will get the expected result. `return (T) conv.ConvertFromString(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? string.Empty : value);` OR  `return (T) conv.ConvertFromString(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? default(string) : value);`